# how can i append list into another outer list?

Tags: python, list

```
i=0
p=0
intervals_list=[]
zero_list=[]          
nonZero_list=[]        
nonZero_small=[]        
nonZero_big=[]
...
while p<len(intervals_list):
        while p in nonZero_list:

nonZero_small.append(intervals_list[nonZero_list[nonZero_list.index(p)]])
                p+=1
                if p not in nonZero_list:
                        if p-1 in nonZero_list:
                                print(nonZero_small)
                                nonZero_big.append([nonZero_small])
        p+=1
        del nonZero_small[0:]
print(nonZero_big)**
```

---

hi guys.
this is my code using python.
the problem is about appending inner list(`nonZero_small`) to outer list(`nonZero_big`).
when i print out `nonZero_small` (in line 16) it doing well.
and i tried to append `nonZero_small` to `nonZero_big`(another list that i want to append `nonZero_small`). (in line 18)
but when i try to print out `nonZero_big`, it works like this.

```
[[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[
]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]],
 [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[
]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]],
 [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[
]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]],
 [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], ....... , [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], 
[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]]]
```

actually the length of list is correct. but why the value inside did not appended? i need your help. thank you.

Comment: because of this: `del nonZero_small[0:]`. Also, off-topic: this expression: `nonZero_list[nonZero_list.index(p)]` is equal to.... `p`

Comment: what form is desired? so confuse but `nonZero_big.append([nonZero_small])` has an additional braket `[]`.

Comment: To add to @Tomerikoos comment,  `append` will append a reference to the object (list in this case) not a copy. Because the object being appended is mutable any changes to it will be reflected in all references to it

Comment: You probably want to use `extend` rather than `append`

Comment: Because he says that the length of the list is actually OK, I am guessing he simply wants to do `append(nonZero_small)` without wrapping in another list...

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you for comment me. yeah you are definitely right. but when i try it with 'intervals_list[nonZero_list[p]]' , the error like 'IndexError: list index out of range' occurs.. i don't know why..

Comment: @Lamanus oh yeah that's right. thank you for notice me

Comment: @Tomerikoo And yes! that right. i know the difference between 'append' and 'extend' but in my case, i want to use 'append'. i think it would be better to use 'append'

Comment: @IainShelvington oh! then do you mean that 'del nonZero_small[0:]' will be affect to the appended part as well? that's what i didn't expected

Comment: @konichan7 yes when you pass an object in python you are really only passing a reference to that object
`foo = [1, 2, 3]`
`bar = [foo, foo, foo]`  bar has 3 elements but they are all references to the same list
`foo.append(4)` all the elements in bar will now have 4 appended to them. If you delete elements from foo they will be deleted in all the elements in bar too

Comment: What do you mean? at the end of each iteration of the outer loop, withot any condition, you are deleting the whole list... Even without the referencing probelm that is expected. Why do you delete the lists? And about the error. Notice what I said: `nonZero_list[nonZero_list.index(p)]` is equivalent to `p`. So you need to do: `intervals_list[p]` not `intervals_list[nonZero_list[p]]`

Comment: Ah after reading @IainShelvington 's comment I see the confusion. You meant to "reset" the list before each iteration. Instead, you can do `nonZero_big.append([nonZero_small[:]])` which will append a copy of the list, and then in the star of each iteration simply do `nonZero_small = []` instead of `del`. I believe it to be more pythonic

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you. it is very clear explanation! that's the essential part what i have to know. thanks!

Comment: @Tomerikoo oh yes.. you are right. and now i just solved the problem thanks to your help!! i could never thought that there are clear solution like 'nonZero_small = []' exist.. and 'nonZero_big.append([nonZero_small[:]])' is yes, it is pythonic solution as you said. thank you!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding! And I recommend you find some tutorial or simply try to read about this online as these are funcemental things in Python. That on one side can be confusing, but when mastered, offer great power :) Also watch out from using `[:]` as this creates a "shallow" copy. Meaning, as long as your list is ints that should be fine. But if trying to copy list of lists, the same problem remains. For more complicated copies there exists the `copy` module

Comment: @Tomerikoo oh i see.. yeah that's true. i really need to try to read tutorial first... thanks for your advise!